# "Path Not Found" when using inputBox variables

Tags: vbscript

I am building a script that uses a user's input to create the path for a source folder. If I use a full path (the path that has been comment out), this works. Otherwise I get "Path Not Found". Can someone lead me in the right direction?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFolder : sFolder = "S:\" & newState & "\" & "Section_" & newSection &   "\Images-tracetest"
'Dim sFolder  : sFolder = "S:\SOCAL\Section_31\Images-tracetest"
Dim newState, newSection, newArea, sFile

Call GetNewInputs()
    REM======================New Inputs===============================
Sub GetNewInputs()

    newState = UCase(InputBox("INPUT STATE or REGION:", _
    "INPUT STATE", "SOCAL"))

    newSection = ("Section_" & InputBox("INPUT SECTION NUMBER:", _
    "INPUT SECTION", "31"))

End Sub
For Each sFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files   

    uSplit   = split(file,"_")
    newArea    = uSplit(ubound(uSplit) - 1)

    If InStr(sFile.Name, "CC") > 0 Then     
    WScript.Echo "We found a CC file! File is" & (sFile.name)   
    Else
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it throw an error. You are creating a variable sFolder before you are getting user inputs. hence, it does not matter even if the user inputs them, they are never being used. The Dim statement or variable initialization happens at the very start when initialized outside any sub or function. You have to do something like this

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
**public sFolder** 
'Dim sFolder  : sFolder = "S:\SOCAL\Section_31\Images-tracetest"
Dim newState, newSection, newArea, sFile

Call GetNewInputs()
    REM======================New Inputs===============================
Sub GetNewInputs()

newState = UCase(InputBox("INPUT STATE or REGION:", _
"INPUT STATE", "SOCAL"))

newSection = ("Section_" & InputBox("INPUT SECTION NUMBER:", _
"INPUT SECTION", "31"))
**sFolder = "S:\" & newState & "\" & "Section_" & newSection &   "\Images-tracetest"**


End Sub
For Each sFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files   

    uSplit   = split(file,"_")
    newArea    = uSplit(ubound(uSplit) - 1)

    If InStr(sFile.Name, "CC") > 0 Then     
        WScript.Echo "We found a CC file! File is" & (sFile.name)   
    Else
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You might wish to add: Adding `Option Explicit` at the start is very important for stopping these kinds of errors

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you add "Section_" twice:

```
sFolder = "S:\" & newState & "\" & "Section_" & newSection &   "\Images-tracetest"


newSection = ("Section_" & InputBox("INPUT SECTION NUMBER:", _
    "INPUT SECTION", "31"))
```

A diagnostic .Echo of `sFolder` would have been a good idea.